# unable to login through ssh with ssh user@ip

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla

I have generated the ssh keygen using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C [USERNAME]
```

following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance), and have pasted the public key to the google virtual server ssh list.

But when i'm logging to server through ssh using `ssh user@ip` i'm getting `Permission denied (publickey)`. But using `ssh -vvv -i .ssh/id_rsa user@ip` I'm able to login.

when i'm logging trough ssh `user@ip` i'm getting a input bar for password like:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

But the problem is I'm not able to login in **FileZilla** with these credentials, it is giving `Trust new Hostkey: Once`.

This is the first Time dealing with SSH so any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: SSH != FTP, what is the output of `ssh -vvv user@ip`? Clarify what is the question here.

Comment: @Jakuje Please see the update. i know SSH != FTP but previously same credential was working for ftp also but now it is not.

Comment: FPT does not have host keys, so it is probably not FTP, but SFTP. To the passphrase, your key is encrypted, because you added a passphrase during the generation. You need to enter this passphrase to use this key.

Comment: @Jakuje how to get this.suggest something.

Comment: @Jakuje i'm using filezilla.

Comment: Do you have a `~/.ssh/config` file that is specifying the identity file as `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` for the target server, overriding your user's identity file?

Comment: @steeldriver no i don't.

Comment: Well according to your output, **something** is causing ssh to use identity file `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` instead of `~/.ssh/id_rsa` when you specify `user@ip` - you need to find what (config file, alias, ... )

Comment: @steeldriver thanks mate. With your last comment i solved my problem.The problem was i used root login in my local system.